# Mobile internet doesn't work on browsers with VPN turned off, but it works in some apps, and works via Wi-Fi in all apps

Tags: internet

I cannot use any browser with VPN turned off using mobile internet, but I can use other apps, such as BBC or Viber. I also can access the internet via Wi-Fi with VPN turned off. I have resetted APN settings many times, but it will not work. I cannot turned off proxy because there is no such an option. The proxy section is blank. When I fill in the blank with some random letters, and then blank it again, the internet begins to work, and after a few searches on the browser stops. Actually, when I change some other sections of APN the internet starts working, but then stops. Tell me please what is wrong. I am clueless about whether or not the problem is with the tablet or the mobile data provider. Because when I put a SIM card from a different provider into my tablet, it worked. And when I put my SIM card into another device, it also worked in that device. I called the company for help. They say that my APN settings was out of order. They sent me new ones. That also didn't solve the problem I have even resetted the tablet to factory settings. To my chagrin, it hasn't worked.

Comment: Make sure proxy is turned off in mobile data settings (APN), could be the culprit here, some proxy may be configured to work on specific sites or apps but on on some, alternatively reset APN settings

Comment: You are right. It has to do with proxy, but I cannot turn it off; there is no such an option. I can just fill in some data in the proxy section. It is blank.  What I did is I entered some random letters, and then blank it again. It worked, but it worked only for a few minutes. Then it stoped.

Comment: It worked a few times I repeated that, and now it doesn't work even if I fill in the blank and clear it.

Comment: And by the way I had not had such broblem before on the device I use.

Comment: Try resetting APN **setting to default**, Settings>MObile Network>Access Point names> Reset to default

Comment: I have done many times, and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to settings>system>reset options
click on "Reset Wi_fi, mobile & bluetooth.

This will however reset your your phone network settings

I had experienced a similar situation and this was the only solution that worked for me.

Did this work for you?

Comment: It have resetted it; nfortunatly, it hasn't worked